# Python2 & 3: embedded board, read USB data

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded, usb

I have an embedded board (ATMEL micro) that TX data to USB port.

Now if I try to read these data with a simple "print" the result is:

[image]

The first group of data (red) not have to go until they are "stable" (i.e. list of 5 elements: green data)!

How to do?

Here is my first simple sample:

```
data = []
while len(data) != 5:
    ser = serial.Serial(strPort, 115200)
    line=ser.readline()
    ...???...
```

...and then? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just split the input line.

```
data = []
ser = serial.Serial(strPort, 115200)
while len(data) != 5:
    data = ser.readline().decode('ascii').split('\t')
```

Comment: Python 2 works fine, but Python 3 I have:


data=ser.readline().split('\t')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I used this code:

    `data[]
    ser=serial.Serial(strPort, 9600, timeout=1)
    raw_data=ser.read(9999)
    if len(raw_data) > 0:
      packet="{0}".format(raw_data.decode('ISO8859.15'))
      data=raw_data.split("#")`


and it works fine.
Is there a "better pythonic way"?

Answer (score 0):

Could you filter the reading to something like:

```
line=ser.readline()
if line[0,5] == "b' -"
    #Process the data
```

Do all the lines you want to read start with the same "b' -" string?

Comment: Yes, but I have this error:

<!-- language: python -->

if line[0,5] == "b' -":
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: P.S.: Sorry, but I don't understand how to write!